# Tiny windows console_only DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp, console

Looking for %subj% IPv4 tool to use in windows shell script. Need following actions by the shell script runtime:

- start listening [on specific interface if posible] DHCP server
- DHCP server catch first query and assing addr/netmask/gateway/dns1/dns2 in the reply
- DHCP server print assigned IP address [and possible mac address of client] into STDOUT and terminate
- shell script continue running and process outputted informations

Spend a time with google but found nothing usable. Anyone have idea?